# PHP has no access to files on external drive (MacOS)

Tags: php, macos, apache, filesystems, file-permissions

There is an error on attempt to access any files or directories on external volume:

> Warning: file_get_contents(/Volumes/Disk/Folder/File.json): Failed to
> open stream: Operation not permitted

I've tried a lot of things:

- sudo chown -R daemon:daemon …
- sudo chmod -R 0777 …
- Volume > Get info > Ignore ownership on this volume (both On and Off)
- Allowed "Full Disk Access" for httpd in "System Preferences" > "Security & Privacy"
- Made an Alias in httpd.conf

Nothing worked. Same error – Failed to open, Operation not permitted.

chown/chmod commands always work for a system drive, but don't work on a mounted volumes.

This is running under Apache (installed via XAMPP) on MacOS.

Any advice?

Comment: If you are running in an Apache web server, it is the server that needs to be allowed to see the folders you want to access in PHP. So you need to [look at Aliasing the directory you want to access using the ALIAS](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html) in your VirtualHost (or host) definition